# How to retrieve context in SPFx 1.1.0?

Tags: spfx, react

Good morning,

I need to create a spfx element to sharepoint 2016. the project dependencies are:

```
"react": "15.4.2",
"react-dom": "15.4.2",
"@types/react": "0.14.46",
"@types/react-dom": "0.14.18",
"@types/react-addons-shallow-compare": "0.14.17",
"@types/react-addons-update": "0.14.14",
"@types/react-addons-test-utils": "0.14.15",
"@microsoft/sp-core-library": "~1.1.0",
"@microsoft/sp-webpart-base": "~1.1.0",
"@microsoft/sp-lodash-subset": "~1.1.0",
"@microsoft/sp-office-ui-fabric-core": "~1.4.0-0",
"@types/webpack-env": "1.13.1",
"@types/es6-promise": "0.0.33"
```

How do I get the pageContext and the httpClient?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From anywhere in the Web Part class (for example the `render()` method), you should be able to access `this.context.pageContext` and `this.context.spHttpClient` or `this.context.httpClient`.

This would be in the `/src/webparts/helloWorld/HelloWorldWebPart.ts` file. (Replace `HelloWorld` with whatever you named your web part.)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response.

in my sharepoint 2016 environment this.context is an empty object {}

Comment: Is the web part [added](https://youtu.be/LGLMxnmHk6U?t=887) to a page? Could you paste the code you are using to access this.context? I don't have a working SP2016 dev environment to test it myself unfortunately. As an alternative for context, you could access the global variable `_spPageContextInfo` to view the context information. I'm not so sure about an alternative for httpClient - worst case, you could go with vanilla `fetch` or `jQuery.ajax` to make those requests.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the images to see how to get and send pageContext and spHttpClient to you components.
[image]

your props should look like this:

[image]

Last step is to get them in your component where all code is by just typing 
this.props.pageContext & this.props.spHttpClient under your render() method.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response.

in my sharepoint 2016 environment this.context is an empty object {}